# Any difference between とは思う and と思う?

Tags: grammar, particle-は

When expressing a thought, can とは思う and と思う be used interchangeably, or is there a more specific reason to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you heard about the difference between が and は, the existence of は there plays *basically* a similar role. (Maybe [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/45489) helps).

One of the functions/meaning of は is 取り立て, which means it indicates the speaker 'picks up' from multiple things.

と思う is the neutral *to think that....*. Adding は indicates that there are other things the speaker is thinking and from which the speaker 'picks up' what they say.

For example, 彼が悪いと思う means just *I think he is to blame*. 彼が悪いとは思う basically means the same, but implies the speaker is thinking something else too, and sounds like more nuanced (e.g., if the issue is between him and some other guy, *he is to blame, but there are things the other shouldn't have done and the other is partially to blame too*)